# Locating values of a node that has two relevant attributes on XPath

Tags: html, python-2.7, xpath

I have an HTML document full of tags that look like that:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Apple Crisp IV" />
<meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="True" />
```

I need to extract the itemprop as the key and the content as the value.

---

**EDIT**: I don't **necessarily** have the meta tag, I need something to not rely on the type of element.

---

I'm using python to do it, and I get all the HTML body to parse.

I have tried:

```
for item in response.xpath('//@itemprop'):
        data  = item.xpath('[@content]')
        print data
```

The 'item' gets all the itemprop elements.
The 'data' part doesn't work.

How do I find the content attribute only in the already found itemprop elements?

I've looked for an answer, but all the people seem to only want to find one element, and a specific one, like this:

```
 ("//@*[name()='itemprop' or name()='content']")
```

This doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the context-specific `@itemprop` and `@content`:

```
In [1]: {elm.xpath("@itemprop").extract_first(): elm.xpath("@content").extract_first() for elm in response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop and @content]")}
Out[1]: {u'mainEntityOfPage': u'True', u'name': u'Apple Crisp IV'}
```

The `//meta[@itemprop and @content]` would filter `meta` elements having both `itemprop` and `content` attributes.

Comment: Thanks, @alecxe !
However, I need to retrieve also elements that are not meta.

Comment: @ElviraGandelman sure, okay then, use `*` in place of `meta`.